# Eclipse method call refactoring

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor some code in the following pattern:

```java
// from
object1.foo(object2).bar() ;

// to
fooBar(object1, object2) ;
```

where

- object1 is a subtype of SuperClass
- object2 is a String
- fooBar is in a utilities class which needs to be imported

For context, the change is due to foo() returning null in some cases, which leads to NullPointerExceptions when bar() is called.
fooBar() first checks if null would be returned by foo(), and if so returns a default value, else calls bar() and returns that.

**I'm using Eclipse, and I'm wondering if there is a good way to do this, instead of manually changing every occurrence using regex in a File Search or something.**

**EDIT - more info in response to comments:**

*I do not have control over the implementation of foo().*

Regarding object1 being a subclass of SuperClass:

```
//in some cases this happens
SuperClass object1 = new SuperClass(/*whatever*/) ;

//in other cases this happens
ChildClass object1 = new ChildClass (/*whatever*/) ;
```

I though I should mention it, as it might affect how to search for object1.

A [maybe] clearer version of before and after code:

```
//before
Object result = object1.foo("a string").bar() ;
//NullPointerException if foo() returns null! :(

//after
Object result = fooBar(object1, "a string") ;
```

Meanwhile, in a separate utility class, there exists:

```
public static Object fooBar(SuperClass obj, String str) {
    Object result = DEFAULT_RESULT ;

    if (obj != null && str != null && obj.fooAble(str)) {
        result = obj.foo(str).bar() ;
    }

    return result ;
}
```

Comment: You put one foo for every object vs one foobar for all objects? Certainly decreases memory needed. At least 4 bytes per object.

Comment: In some occurrences in the code object1's type is SuperClass; in others, object1's type is explicitly ChildClass, a sub-class of SuperType.

Comment: Do you have control over the implementation of `foo`?  It would be easier to just have it never return null -- instead return a default instance for which `bar()` just returns the default value.

Comment: I have added more info in response to your comments.  Thanks!

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I'm not sure what you mean. If you mean changing the implementation of foo(), I cannot.  If you mean doing a null check each time, I'm trying to minimize code duplication by using a utility method.

Comment: Within a single class file, you could select `object1.foo(object2).bar()` and Extract Method on it, then replace the body of the new method with what you want, then inline the new method, but I don't know a way to do this across all files.

Comment: @CarlManaster The problem is this occurs multiple times, across multiple classes, in multiple packages.  I was hoping to leverage Eclipse's refactoring capabilities or something.

Comment: Looks like find and replace is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I found solution even spent on this 3 years of my life! :)

Actually solution based on code refactoring that replaces one method call with another.
Example:
Before we have: `obj1.method1(){};` `obj2.method2(obj1){ obj1.method1(); };`

After applying eclipse refactoring "Inline ..." we will have every call of `obj2.method2(obj1);` replaced with call `obj1.method1();`

So for your case:

1. Make backup copy of source files with implementation of method foo, bar, fooBar;
2. Then replace implementation of fooBar as: fooBar(object1, object2) { return this; };
3. Replace implementation of method bar() with: bar() { return this; };
4. Replace implementation of method foo(object2) with: foo(object2) { return fooBar(this,object2); };
5. Then apply to any call of bar() eclipse refactoring "Inline ...", it just dissolves all bar() calls;
6. Apply again "Inline ..." for any call of `object1.foo(object2)` which replace all such calls with `fooBar(this,object2);`
7. Restore implementation of each method from backup copy;

That's it!